# libpcap, payload offset 66 but sizeof(headers) + doff = 62

Tags: unix, tcp, network-programming, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I am spending my sunday on understanding packet sniffing with libpcap and I came so far that I can read packets and metadata. When I was checking my code by sniffing on some packets, I found that I must have an error somewhere.

When I sniff the webpage from my father: http://www.telpho.de , I get the whole server response back. Starting from 200 OK until ... But on each packet, there are 4 bytes in the beginning which are not ASCII. In the code below, when i change the for loop to (i = 0), the 4 bytes get printed as well. When i leave it at (i = 4), then the payload gets displayed perfectly from the first ASCII character received.

My question now, do I calculate data_offset wrong? Are there any flags which I didnt set? Did i forgot to count the tcp options in ?

I also thought it has maybe to do with padding. The TCP standard says that the TCP header length should be a multiple of 32. But 32 - 20 = 12.. so this are 3 bytes difference.

Could it for example be that the calculation is like this?

```
TCP_HDR_SIZE = 32
sizeof(struct tcphdr) = 20
tcp->doff = 8    

sizeof(struct tcphdr) + tcp->doff = 28
TCP_HDR_SIZE - 28 = 4    <--- the 4 bytes i am looking for??? Maybe options?
```

Here is the code:

```
void handle_packet_ip(const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char* data) {
  struct ip *ip;
  struct tcphdr *tcp;
  int ip_len;
  int data_offset;
  int payload_len;
  int i;
  unsigned char* payload;

  ip = (struct ip*)(data + sizeof(struct ether_header));
  ip_len = (ip->ip_hl & 0x0f) * 4;

  tcp = (struct tcphdr*)(data + sizeof(struct ether_header) + ip_len);
  printf("sizeof(ip): %d\n", sizeof(struct ip));
  printf("ip_len: %d\n", ip_len);
  printf("sizeof(ether_header): %d\n", sizeof(struct ether_header));
  printf("sizeof(tcp): %d\n", sizeof(struct tcphdr));

  data_offset = sizeof(struct ether_header) + ip_len + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + tcp->doff;
  payload_len = header->len - data_offset;

  payload = (unsigned char*)(data + data_offset);

  printf("IP PACKET\n");
  printf("\tlen: %u\n", ntohs(ip->ip_len));
  printf("\tsrc: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
  printf("\tdst: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));
  printf("\thl: %d\n", (ip->ip_hl & 0x0f));

  printf("READ TCP\n");
  printf("\tsrc port: %u\n", ntohs(tcp->source));
  printf("\tdst port: %u\n", ntohs(tcp->dest));
  printf("\tdata_offset: %d\n", data_offset); 
  printf("\tdoff: %d-%d\n", tcp->doff, ntohs(tcp->doff));
  printf("\tpayload len: %d\n", payload_len);
  printf("\tFLAGS\n");
  printf("\t\tFIN: %i\n", tcp->fin);
  printf("\t\tSYN: %i\n", tcp->syn);
  printf("\t\tACK: %i\n", tcp->ack);
  printf("PAYLOAD: \n");
  **for (i = 4; i < payload_len; ++i) {**
    printf("%c", payload[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  printf("\n");
  printf("END OF PAYLOAD\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Grabbed Packet:
Length: 74
    Capture Length: 74
sizeof(ip): 20
ip_len: 20
sizeof(ether_header): 14
sizeof(tcp): 20
IP PACKET
len: 60
src: 80.237.132.106
dst: 192.168.0.17
hl: 5
READ TCP
src port: 80
dst port: 57662
data_offset: 62     **this should be 64 ??**
doff: 8
payload len: 10
FLAGS
    FIN: 0
    SYN: 1
    ACK: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem correct,

```
data_offset = sizeof(struct ether_header) + ip_len + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + tcp->doff
```

tcp->doff already includes the tcp header, and it is in multiple of 4 bytes. So you'd want

```
 data_offset = sizeof(struct ether_header) + ip_len + tcp->doff * 4;
```

Using just sizeof(struct tcphdr) does not account for any TCP options that might occur.

Note that your code assumes a whole lot:

- Assumes no ethernet vlan
- Assumes an IP packet is above ethernet (and not e.g. arp or stp)
- Assumes TCP above IP
- Assumes you've actually captured all the data needed. (i.e. you should verify that the lengths does not exceed header->cap_len)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. yeah my code is really really basic :-) I am just starting with learning all this stuff..